# Graphviz left-justify edge label text

Tags: python-3.x, label, graphviz, text-justify

I am trying to fruitlessly trying to figure out how I can left-justify my edge labels in graphviz. If anyone has a solution please help!

I have created a dataset to map object dependencies--then reading into graphviz via iterrows.

Here is my Python code that works--but renders my edge labels with text that is centre justified:

```
u = Digraph('unix',
            filename='unix.gv',
            node_attr={'color': 'lightblue', 
                       'style': 'filled', 
                       'fontname':'arial', 
                       'shape':'box'},
           edge_attr={'dir':'back',
                     'fontname':'arial',
                     'fontsize':'12'})

u.attr(size='20,20')

for index, row in d.iterrows():
    u.edge(row.var_target, row.var_source, label=str(row.bizlogic))

u
```

[image: shows central justified edge label]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace the \n at the end of each line with a \l (for left justify) you should get the desired output (https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/attrs.html#k:escString).  An example (in straight Graphviz):

```
digraph G {
    rankdir=LR;
    a [ label ="Graphs can\lbe fun\l"];
    b [ label ="left\lmiddle\nright\r  " ];
    a -> b [label ="Edges can\lalso\rbe fun\lI'm told\r"];
}
```

Giving:

[image]

Comment: Thanks--I had seen this elsewhere but was hoping to have the option of just applying left-align to the label instead of messing with the string itself. However, have applied to my dataframe column with d['edge_label']=d.edge_label.str.replace('\n','\l') and now looking good