# Right-justify list in graphviz, python

Tags: python, graphviz

I am unable to get a graphviz node label to be right justified when joining strings from a list.
If I attach '\n' and '\r' to either end, the justification works, but it still shows the list elements (brakcets & quotes):

```
label_list = ['car','button','cloth']
label = ['\n' + s + '\r' for s in label_list]
```

[image]

If I use join, the right-justification is lost:

```
label_list = ['car','button','cloth']
label = ['\n' + s '\r' for s in label_list]
label = ''.join(label)
```

[image]

Per sroush comment, removing '\n' gives:

[image](or something similar to first example if join is not used).

What I'd like is simply:

[image]

Comment: the best reference I could find: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65162650/graphviz-left-justify-edge-label-text

Comment: Think of '\r' as including a '\n' also.  So remove the '\n' from your program and see what happens.

Comment: @sroush thanks, I updated the question with this recommendation; still no solution.

Comment: I assume that under the hood a `dot file is generated, can't you see what the content of this file is? (from this probably you can draw conclusions like the needed number of backslashes ,  might be you need `\\n`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By converting the list to a string and removing each of the list elements (brackets, commas, etc), I get the desired result.

```
label_list = ['car','button','cloth']
label = [s + '\r' for s in label_list]
label = str(label)[1:-1].replace(',','').replace("'",'')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Graphviz-only (no Python) solution:

```
graph j {  
 A [label="car\rbutton\rcloth\rmuch more\r"]  
}
```

Giving:
[image]

Comment: This is similar to my first comment above. I do need a python solution. Thanks!